# how to set the text in textbox at the begining

Tags: jsp, textarea

I am aware that when a text is displayed in a `textarea` the text will be displayed at the beginning. but in my case, the text will appear to the end of the `textarea` creating some spaces at the beginning. so when I open the `jsp` page, initially I cant see any text, I need to scroll down to see it.
please guide me why this problem exist.

```
<textarea class="mintbox" rows="2" cols="20" name="receivingBankAddress">  
    <bean:write name="PRForm" property="receivingBankAddress"/>
</textarea>
```

Comment: Please share your jsp code and please check your code where you are setting value of textbox.

Comment: <textarea class="mintbox" rows="2" cols="20" name="intermediaryBankAddress" >
<bean:write name="PRForm" property="intermediaryBankAddress"/></textarea>

Comment: This is where I am setting the data  @VPK : prBankDetailsVO.setIntermediaryBankAddress(rsPRBankDetails
       .getString("bdt_intermediary_bank_addr"));

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing with `<bean:write name="PRForm" property="intermediaryBankAddress"/>`. I guess you are setting value to textarea right? Also please  add your code in your question so it can explain your problem.

Comment: yes thats right. all the other fields are getting displayed properly except textbox.

Comment: Is `PRForm` the name of your bean? If yes, then you can try `<textarea class="mintbox" rows="2" cols="20" name="intermediaryBankAddress" value="${PRForm.intermediaryBankAddress}" />`. You will not need `<bean:write>`

Comment: Or simply, `<form:textarea path="intermediaryBankAddress"  />`. By adding library `<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>`.

Comment: This is the code from the browser, when i tried your first solution, there is space before add1, which is the value (actuall there is a lot of space. but when i post the comment it gets reduced)                                           <textarea class="mintbox" rows="2" cols="20" name="intermediaryBankAddress" value="                                                                              add1">

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your `jsp` code like this,

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>
<html>
<body>
<textarea class="mintbox" rows="2" cols="20" name="intermediaryBankAddress" value="${fn:trim(PRForm.intermediaryBankAddress)}" />
</body>
</html>
```

Here, you can add the `jstl` taglib to trim the unnecessary spaces from your value. `${fn:trim(PRForm.intermediaryBankAddress)}` will trim the value.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was and  were in different line and the space between them was considered.

when I made sure only  is between then the problem was solved. there was no space.